# Making a gwt button transparent

Tags: java, gwt

I have some buttons in a GWT based application. Each of those buttons include an image. The idea it is to show only the Image contained within the button, but not the button itself, but inherit the button capabilities and properties, as i am using the buttons inside a hashMap:

```
final Map<Button, Integer> buttonRowMap = new HashMap<Button, Integer>();
```

I can show you the code related to the "problem":

```
final Button gu = new Button();
buttonRowMap.put(gu, i);
Image imggu = new Image("Imagenes\\Add.png");
imggu.setSize("25%", "25%");
gu.getElement().appendChild(imggu.getElement());
gu.getElement().setId(""+i);
gu.setTitle("Modify");
```

The result i want to achieve it is to show the Image in my gwt as if it was a button, but without showing the button that the image it is embedded in.

Can anyone help me out?.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to extend `ButtonBase` instead of `Button`?

Comment: Extend ButtonBase? Sorry i dont know what you mean by that, Arnaud.

Comment: If you don't want to display buttons, why not get rid of them and put the Images directly inside the Map? You can add click handlers to images as well.

Comment: Thank you David Levesque, thats exactly what im doing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing this with css.

```
button.setSyleName("add")
```

Then in css

```
button.add {
  background: url(images/add.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  border: none;
}
```

You would need to put the add.png in your public directory in /images/add.png

The other option is that you can use a CssResource and a sprite to add the background image to your button.

Comment: Although, this is not what i am doing, i find that your answer its perfectly valid and thus, I tick it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: You should checkout the cssresource and the sprite functionality. It will speed up your ui since it will encode the image for you when compiling and inlines the encoded image into your css. This way the browser doesn't have to fetch the image as a separate http get. http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#CssResource